# userDefaults being removed after force app crash

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

Not sure if this is a bug or what.  I have two different values I'd like to set in userDefaults, one is `isLoggedIn` state and another `isOwner` state, which is a priority/permission.

When the user first logs in, everything works fine. Both states are saved inside the console if user is the owner and is logged in. Have called `print(UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation())` and they are both printed to the console.

I can use the app for however long and it works fine.  Nevertheless, if I force crash the app ( Double tap the home button and remove the app from running in the background), one of the states ends up getting removed. It can be either of the states, forcing the app to become buggy.

Is this a bug? How can I avoid this?

```
extension UserDefaults {

enum UserDefaultsKeys: String {
    case isOwner
    case isLoggedIn
    case latitude
    case longitude
}


func setIsOwner(value: Bool) {
    set(value, forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.isOwner.rawValue)
    synchronize()
}

func setIsLoggedIn(value: Bool) {
    set(value, forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.isLoggedIn.rawValue)
    synchronize()
}

func setCoordinates(coordinate: Coordinate) {

    set(coordinate.latitude, forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.latitude.rawValue)
    set(coordinate.longitude, forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.longitude.rawValue)

    synchronize()
}

func isOwner() -> Bool {
    return bool(forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.isOwner.rawValue)
}

func isLoggedIn() -> Bool {
    return bool(forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.isLoggedIn.rawValue)
}

func coordinates() -> (latitude: Double, longitude: Double)? {
    if let latitude = string(forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.latitude.rawValue),
        let longitude = string(forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.longitude.rawValue) {
        return (latitude: Double(latitude)!, longitude: Double(longitude)!)
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
}
```

so to set the `isLoggedIn` state or `isOwner` state:

```
UserDefaults.standard.setIsLoggedIn(value: true)
UserDefaults.standard.setIsOwner(value: isOwner)  // isOwner is a boolean value
```

This is only set called in two places, when a user created an account or when a user signs in.

And then I only remove the UserDefaults in one place, when the user logs out:

```
for key in Array(UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation().keys) {
    if key != UserDefaults.UserDefaultsKeys.latitude.rawValue &&
        key != UserDefaults.UserDefaultsKeys.longitude.rawValue {
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: key)
    }
}
```

I can log in and print both values to the console fine.  If I force crash the app within 5 seconds or 5 minutes, one of the UserDefaults values that are set dissapear

```
extension UIViewController
{

func isOwner() -> Bool {
    return UserDefaults.standard.isOwner()
}

func isLoggedIn() -> Bool {
    return UserDefaults.standard.isLoggedIn()
}
}
```

.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if isOwner() {
        sectionOne = ["Account details", "Profile"]
        sectionTwo = ["Posts you've liked", "Messages"]
        sectionFour = "Log out"
    } else if isLoggedIn() {
        sectionOne = ["Account details"]
        sectionTwo = ["Posts you've liked"]
        sectionFour = "Log out"
    } else {
        sectionOne.removeAll()
        sectionTwo.removeAll()
        sectionFour = "Log in"
    }
}
tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Think Instagram with the use of a `UITabBarController`.  The code above would exist in the last tab, the `Accounts` tab.  When the view appears it would relayout the tableView as needed.

Comment: Add `UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()` after setting value it. This thought is going to be deprecated but will serve the purpose for you.   That will *after writing in order to notify another program to read*.

Comment: @rptwsthi I do, all values that I want to save are saved.  It's after I force crash and restart the app some of the userdefaults are removed

Comment: Maybe you can try `UserDefaults(suiteName: "myDefaults")`.

Comment: @rptwsthi Unfortunately/fortunately, `synchronize()` is never needed (the system does it automatically now), and when it's needed, it's useless, because the issue comes from an anti-pattern or an external cause, and the  actual solution is to debug and refactor. :)

Comment: @EricAya how can I debug and refactor something like this?

Comment: It depends on how your code is architectured. I would start by noting every place where these values are saved, and where they should be saved, every place where they are loaded again, and where they should be loaded again. Then compare with what you think it should be. Maybe you missed a part. // Also, *remove* any `synchronize()` because this could actually make the issue worse (this doesn't only saves, this really synchronizes *both ways* for all defaults for all domains and could have unwanted behavior). // And if you want good answers: show your code. :)

Comment: @EricAya Added some code

Comment: @luke How do you know the values disappear? I mean: where in your code workflow do you load the values then notice that one is missing?

Comment: @EricAya added some code - I navigate to the Account tab by just loading the app then tapping the 4th tab.

Comment: The code looks correct to me. I could be missing something, of course. Upvoted, I hope someone will find a solution for you. Good luck.

Comment: @EricAya is there any code that runs when app ends running or begins running that should be looked at? Is it just the methods inside the `AppDelegate` that handles this?

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? @luke